# Show that S is closed but not compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

> Show that $S$={$(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: x^3+y^4-z^2=1$} is closed but not compact where $\mathbb R^3$ is the usual topology.

Can anyone explain how to go about answering this? I have to show that this is closed but not bounded but I don't know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: To show that it is closed, identify it as preimage of a continuous mapping $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ of a closed set.

Comment: Compact in $\Bbb R^3$ means closed _and bounded_. Since we're told that $S$ is closed, or only hope is that it's not bounded.

Comment: Hint: Use Heine Borel Theorem to prove its not compact

Answer (score 2):

Define $f: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ as 
$$ f(x,y,z) := x^3 + y^4 - z^2 -1 \; .$$
It should be clear, that $f$ is a continous function. Note that 
$$ S = f^{-1}(\{0\}) \; .$$
Since $f$ is continuous and $\{ 0 \}$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, we deduce that $S$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^3$.

It remains to show, that $S$ is unbounded. Let $x,y \geq 1$ arbitrary. Then 
$$ (x,y,z) \in S \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \underbrace{ x^3 + y^4 - 1 }_{\geq 0} = z^2  \; .$$
So we see, that there exists a $z \in \Bbb R$, such that $(x,y,z) \in S$. This shows that $S$ is unbounded, since we can choose $x,y \geq 1$ as big as we want.